# Visual studio 2010:  modelling enterprise app with multiple subsystems

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, architecture, uml

I am modelling an enterprise app using VS2010.

The app consists of several sub systems. I envisage each sub system to be a separate project on its own. During my "brain storming" phase, I would like to show all of these sub systems in one diagram.

I am confused as to how (or indeed whether it is possible) to show all the sub systems in one high level diagram, and yet somehow "drill down" into the subsystems to see their domain models etc - whilst each subsystem is a separate project ini its own right.

I am new to VisualStudio, so I would appreciate any help in showing me how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

When you are developing in VS you have a VS Solution. A VS Solution often has several projects, for example data layer in one, data transfer objects in another and UI in a third.

Very often a VS Solution will be a single "app", but it does not have to be. You can have all projects in a single solution and use folders to group projects by subsystems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the reln between a solution and projects. However, somethings still remain unclear - for example - (1). which project should contain the "master" high level diagram that shows the various subsystems and how they relate to each other? (2). Assuming that I have a project that displays the "master" high level diagram, can I "drill down" (e.g. double click) on a subsystem in the master diagram and go to its project, so that I can view the class diagrams etc in greater detail.